# Spyder never "quits"

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, anaconda, spyder

I loaded up Anaconda and realized there is more stuff there than I can absorb in my lifetime. However, I did load Spyder and pasted in a working program that runs without error in PyCharm and Thonny.

```
"""Create a 2 button window"""
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
    
#write slogan out in a message box
def write_slogan():
    messagebox.showinfo("our message",
                        "tkinter is easy to use")

#set up the window
root = tk.Tk()              #get the window
root.geometry("100x100+300+300")    #x, y window size and position

#create Hello button
slogan = Button(root,
                   text="Hello",
                   command=write_slogan)
slogan.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)

#create exit button with red letters
button = Button(root, 
                   text="QUIT", 
                   fg="red", 
                   command=quit)
button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10)

#start running the tkinter loop
root.mainloop()
```

It may not surprise Spyder mavens, but I was surprised to see that it did not recognize "quit" However, I replaced it with

```
command=sys.exit
```

and that at least compiled.
[image]

However, when I ran it, the window appeared UNDER the Spyder window. I found it in the task bar. BUT, when I clicked in the Quit button, the program just hung. I had to go to the console and and type
`quit`
to stop the process.
I guess Spyder isn't really intended for GUI programming.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `button = Button(root, text="QUIT",fg="red",command=root.quit)`

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: What about `root.destroy`, `quit` is a inbuilt python function and not something with tkinter.

Comment: root.destroy does work in Spyder, but it is disappointing that it does not recognize a standard Python function. Spyder also flags LEFT and RIGHT as "may be undefined or defined form star imports" which is just silly.

Comment: But keep in mind that `quit` is not the proper way to close a window. for tkinter.

Comment: That is true, but the fact that the keyword is not even recognized is wronger. And the fact the sys.exit hangs the program us just a bug.

Comment: Hmmmm maybe spyder is not for GUI development